# How to add attributes using codeigniter form helper

Tags: php, html, forms, codeigniter

I can't find the answer to this. Say I output a input field using the code igniter form helper:

```
echo form_input('username','username');
```

How do I add attributes such as `class` or `id` to that `input` filed?

Comment: see:: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html

Answer (score 9):

you can pass an associative array containing any data you wish your form to contain:

try this

```
 $data = array(
          'name'        => 'username',
          'id'          => 'username',
          'class'       => 'username',
          'value'       => 'username',
        );

 echo form_input($data);
```

Please go through the userguide. it is clearly mentioned there with examples. [link](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html) to userguide