# how to style the form using css in codeigniter

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter

Is it possible to add css on codeigniter ?? Please help me to add css on the below code

```
  echo validation_errors();
  echo "email :".form_input('email', '');
  echo "Password :".form_password('password', '');
  echo "Password Confirmation :".form_password('passconf', '');
  echo form_submit('submit', 'Submit');
```

- above is my password reset view file , please help me to style the above code with any css example
- How to add class to above code ?
- is it possible to add JavaScript ?

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
 and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good Question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$data = array(
  'name'        => 'email',
  'value'          => '',
  'class'       => 'email_Input', // Create class name and use this class name in your .css file
  'style'       => 'height:30px' // Or, write property here itself
);

echo form_input($data);
?>
```

Read [How to add attributes using codeigniter form helper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18588414/how-to-add-attributes-using-codeigniter-form-helper)